# Updating user fields in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to update the core user fields in WooCommerce when I edit a users profile, however, when I save, only the user meta saves.

But the wp_update_user is not saving the distributor name in the billing_company field.

The code is fired in a function called from
`add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'user_profile_update_action');`

The code in the function is ...

```
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'user_profile_update_action');

function user_profile_update_action($user_id) {

  if(isset($_POST['distributor_id']) AND $_POST['distributor_id'] == "|"){
      delete_metadata( $user_id, 'distributor_id', '');
      delete_metadata( $user_id, 'distributor_name', '');
  }else{
      $distributordata = explode("|", $_POST['distributor_id']); // Split the array
      update_user_meta($user_id, 'distributor_id', $distributordata[0] );
      update_user_meta($user_id, 'distributor_name', $distributordata[1] );
      wp_update_user(array('ID' => $user_id, 'billing_company' => $distributordata[1]));
  }
}
```

I've tried update user meta and wp update user but neither want to save billing company.

Answer (score 0):

```
$customer = new WC_Customer( $user_id );
$customer->set_billing_company($distributordata[1]);
$customer->save();
```

Comment: Thanks - this doesnt seem to work. I've placed it inside the function, but the field still isnt updating when I save the profile.